# Python: Append double items to new array

Tags: python, arrays

lets say I have an array "array_1" with these items:

A b A c

I want to get a **new** array "array_2" which looks like this:

b A c A

I tried this:

> array_1 = ['A','b','A','c' ]
>
> array_2 = []
>
> for item in array_1:
>
> ```
> if array_1[array_1.index(item)] == array_1[array_1.index(item)].upper():
>     array_2.append(array_1[array_1.index(item)+1]+array_1[array_1.index(item)])
> ```

The problem: The result looks like this:

b A b A

Does anyone know how to fix this? This would be really great!

Thanks, Nico.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Can you explain what the significance of the upper case letters is?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you need? Just looking at the two example lists I could think of many problems, the simplest of them being "move the first item of the list to the last position"...

Comment: Hi, lets say the upper case letters are names like SMITH and the the lower case letters are first-names like Mike and Judy.

Comment: I'd like to have Mike SMITH and Judy SMITH instead of SMITH Mike and SMITH Judy, but I get Mike SMITH and Mike SMITH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have 2 'A' in your array. In both case for the 'A',

```
array_1[array_1.index(item)+1
```

will equal 'b' because the index method return the first index of 'A'.

To correct this behavior; i suggest to use an integer you increment for each item. In that cas you'll retrieve the n-th item of the array and your program wont return twice the same 'A'.

Responding to your comment, let's take back your code and add the integer:

```
array_1 = ['A','b','A','c' ]

array_2 = []
i = 0
for item in array_1:

if array_1[i] == array_1[i].upper():
    array_2.append(array_1[i+1]+array_1[i])
i = i + 1
```

In that case, it works but be careful, you need to add an if statement in the case the last item of your array is an 'A' for example => array_1[i+1] won't exist.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yes, the 'A's are really the problem. Could you show how this integer would look like? Sry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: `for i in range(len(array_1)): ...`

Comment: Another suggestion: `if array[i].isupper()` is more concise than `if array[i] == array[i].upper()`.

Comment: I know, i just took his code back and added the integer to make is program work. ^^

Answer (score 2):

I think that simple flat list is the wrong data structure for the job if each lower case letter is paired with the consecutive upper case letter. If would turn it into a list of two-tuples i.e.:

```
['A', 'b', 'A', 'c'] becomes [('A', 'b'), ('A', 'c')]
```

Then if you are looping through the items in the list:

```
for item in list:
    print(item[0])    # prints 'A'
    print(item[1])    # prints 'b' (for first item)
```

To do this:

```
input_list = ['A', 'b', 'A', 'c']
output_list = []
i = 0;
while i < len(input_list):
    output_list.append((input_list[i], input_list[i+1]))
    i = i + 2;
```

Then you can swap the order of the upper case letters and the lower case letters really easily using a list comprehension:

```
swapped = [(item[1], item[0]) for item in list)]
```

---

Edit:

As you might have more than one lower case letter for each upper case letter you could use a list for each group, and then have a list of these groups.

```
def group_items(input_list):
    output_list = []
    current_group = []
    while not empty(input_list):
        current_item = input_list.pop(0)
        if current_item == current_item.upper():
            # Upper case letter, so start a new group
            output_list.append(current_group)
            current_group = []
        current_group.append(current_item)
```

Then you can reverse each of the internal lists really easily:

```
[reversed(group) for group in group_items(input_list)]
```

Comment: thanks for your help! The problem is, that there is sometimes more than just one lower case letter between two upper case ones

Comment: Oh okay, maybe do lists of lists then like: `[['A', 'b', 'd'], ['A', 'c']]`. You would have to construct these a bit differently. I could include some code for that in my answer if it would be helpful?

Comment: Oh yes, I hope this would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to your last comment, you can get what you want using this

```
array_1 = "SMITH Mike SMITH Judy".split()

surnames = array_1[1::2]
names = array_1[0::2]

print array_1

array_1[0::2] = surnames
array_1[1::2] = names

print array_1
```

You get:

```
['SMITH', 'Mike', 'SMITH', 'Judy']
['Mike', 'SMITH', 'Judy', 'SMITH']
```

Comment: thanks for your help! the problem is that in some cases, there is more than one prename (but always just one surname)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then you can do this:

It will work for any length of array.

```
array_1 = ['A','b','A','c' ]
array_2 = []
for index,itm in enumerate(array_1):
    if index % 2 == 0:
        array_2.append(array_1[index+1])
        array_2.append(array_1[index])

print array_2
```

Output:

```
['b', 'A', 'c', 'A']
```

Comment: thanks for your help! The problem is, that my arrays have different lengths and there is sometimes more than just one lower case letter between two upper case ones